# Save csv files from the directory as a separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have several files csv in the directory

[image: directory]

What I need to do is to iterate (**specifically iterate**, because I will do other calculations over the data) in the folder over the files and read them using `pandas.read_csv`  as a separate **DataFrames**.

What I have wrote is the following:

```
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    data = pd.read_csv(directory+ '/' +i, encoding="utf8")
```

When I execute the code above it writes down only the last step's data in the df and when I change the code to the one below:

```
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    data[i] = pd.read_csv(directory+ '/' +i, encoding="utf8")
```

`data[i]` is marked by red

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi, if you are getting an error (I assume marked by red means that), you didn't specify that data was a dictionary.

Comment: To store the data in separate dataframes, you could save it in a list like so:

`data = []`, and in your for loop do `data.append(pd.read_csv)`.

You can also save it as a dictionary if you want to keep the filename as a reference like so:

`data = {}` and in the for loop `data[i] = pd.read_csv()`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your 2nd code snippet to be like this, then it should work, and your dictionary will have keys of the name of the file, and the values will be Dataframes of the corresponding data.

```
data = {}
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    data[i] = pd.read_csv(directory+ '/' +i, encoding="utf8")

# or using fancy dictionary comprehensions & f-strings (needs recent python3 release)
data = {path: pd.read_csv(f'{directory}/{path}', encoding="utf8")
    for path in os.listdir(directory)}

# or using pathlib
from pathlib import Path
data = {path.name: pd.read_csv(path, encoding="utf8"
    for path in Path(directory).iterdir()}
```

Comment: By using the first code snippet of your comment I get one dictionary as I understand...is there a way to extract dataframes from it?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you are trying to do. Once the "data" dictionary exists you can either iterate through it, or access individual dataframes by data[filename].